# Limit of a sequence $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{2n^2+n+2}{n\sqrt n}}$

Tags: limits

I am stuck on this question. I am having trouble with the bottom part.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{2n^2+n+2}{n\sqrt n}}$$

I divde the top part by $n^2$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{n^2(2+\frac{n}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^2})}{n\sqrt n}}$$

How do I continue from here? How do I deal with the denominator? Also, does $\frac{n}{n^2}$ goes to infinity?

Comment: $$\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac1n\to0$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {2n^{2}+n+2}{n\sqrt n} >\frac {2n^{2}}{n\sqrt n}=2\sqrt n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2n^{2}+n+2}{n\sqrt{n}}$$,
Since it's of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ we can use the l'hopital rule,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4x+1}{(1.5)\sqrt{x}}$$
Note that $\sqrt{x}=O(4x)$.
Hence the limit diverges.